# how to reshape 3d data for sklearn classifiers

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

in my project i am trying to use sklearn classifiers, but cant input data in a model . shape of data consists of lists with 3 coordinates. the error is ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

[shape of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPDj0.png)

```
dataset1 = pd.read_csv(...)
dataset1 = pd.read_csv(...)
X=dataset1.iloc[:178,2:35]
y = dataset2.iloc[:,2:35]

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=32)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: where is your whole code? where is you define X_Train , y_train? what is X.shape and y.shape?

Comment: You assign to `dataset1` twice, you never assign to `X_train` or `y_train`.  Usually `y_train` contains labels not multiple columns. Can you post samples of your data as text not as an image?

Comment: You can't train a `KNeighborsClassifier` with input of ndim > 2.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny the shape of data :        1    2  3  4 ..... 30
                                                            1  [0.0, 1557.0, 28.0]  ...  [32.0, 1567.0, 1185.0]
                                                             175  [0.0, 1539.0, 48.0]  ...  [32.0, 1564.0, 1206.0]

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny what classifiers can i use, i am trying to predict the belonging of a person's gait by points from two different videos

Comment: I'm not familiar with gait classification. The usual way to train a model to classify 2D input (e.g. labeling images) is a [`CNN`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_Neural_Network) or to reshape your 2D data to a long 1D array, e.g. for [handwritten digits recognition](https://medium.com/@nikhilanandikam/handwritten-digit-recognition-hdr-using-k-nearest-neighbors-knn-f4c794a0282a) (28x28) to (784,1).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.